# MS Access “Compile Error: Label not defined” - Register Form

Tags: ms-access

Can anyone tell me why am I getting a compile error, I really can't work it out.

I am doing a register form in MS Access.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command61_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
If IsNull(UserID) Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered information", , "Error"
ElseIf IsNull(UserName) Or IsNull(Password) Then
    MsgBox "The user name and password fields are requiered", , "Error"
Else
    msg = "Do you want to sumbit your information"
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical
    Title = "Registration Confirmed"
    response = MsgBox(msg, Style, Title)
    If response = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If response = vbNo Then
        Me.Undo
        DoCmd.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
Exit_ErrHandlers:
Exit Sub
ErrHandlers:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub Command62_Click()
Me.Undo
DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

I hope somebody will help me.

Thanks.

Comment: On top of what @smoore4 has given, it's generally useful to rename your controls `Command61` doesn't mean much, while `btnRegister` explains what's going on.  You also have `If response = vbYes Then` and `If response = vbNo Then`.  You can use `Else` or `ElseIf` to join those two blocks together, rather than a separate `If` block.  In this case you could just have `Me.Undo` in the `vbNo` - place the form close outside the IF block as it happens whatever response you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement says this:  `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` but you define your error handler with an "s" - `ErrHandlers:`

Always a good idea to post the exact error message when you have a question like this.  It will help a great deal.